# LIST as parameter in 'run' query

Tags: neo4j, cypher, py2neo

My code should create a set of nodes whose payload should be represented by an arbitrary length array . In other words, this should look like

```
(n:Node {array:...})
```

While it's easy to pull that off with a dictionary like so

```
"MATCH (n) SET n+={param}",param=dict
```

I'm totally at a loss as to how that can be done with a list - especially, one of a length that will only be known at runtime.

I am thinking of embedding a list in a dictionary, but isn't there a more elegant way of doing that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to set an array is to just do this:

```
"MATCH (n) SET n.array = $param", param=list
```

*NOTE: I used the `$param` syntax instead of `{param}`, as the latter is deprecated.*